# Package dependencies can not be resolved

Tags: software-center

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3 32-bit. When I try to download something like wine or chromium out of Ubuntu Software Center it won't let me and says this to me:

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable.
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

What does this mean? I'm not even installing anything right now. How can I fix this so I can download the programs?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that resolve by this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install -y
```

This fixes the dependency issues among rest of your installations.